# Jade - Accessing a variable passed to it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, pug

So I have a user stored in `session` when they log in on my Node.js application. I have admins and default users, if I output `#{session.user.role}` in the Jade template, I get `default` or `admin` appear. And when testing on my page I can hide items on the page using `-if(session.user)` to hide an item if no one is logged in, but how do I hide items for users which aren't admins?

I have tried putting in `-if(session.user.role === 'default')` but I get an error saying `Cannot read property 'role' of undefined`. So that won't work, any ideas on how to do this anyone?

Here is the User Schema using Mongoose:

```
var User = new Schema({
  'key' : {
    unique : true,
    type : Number,
    default: getId
  },
  'username' : { type : String, 
              validate : [validatePresenceOf, 'a Username is required'],
              set : toLower,
              index : { unique : true }
              },
  'password' : String,
  'role' : String,
});
```

Comment: You're saying `session.user.role` outputs default or admin, so it must exist. You sure the undefined-error doesn't just occur for users that are not logged in? If so you could write `if(session.user && session.user.role === 'default')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- if (typeof session.user != 'undefined' && session.user.role === 'default')
```

Comment: Out of interest, would you know how to do this in an `express` route for the Node.js app? I'm routing to a page, but want to shut off access to the page if the user is not an admin. I'm just using a log to console at the moment to print to the console if the user is an admin or not but I get a `session is not defined` error.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, how would you check for someone who is a default user OR not registered? For example if a user is set as `default` or as `admin` the page will load, but if no user is logged in, the error is `role is not defined` as no one is logged in